# Generating the name of the trigger dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to dynamically generate the name of a trigger based on the inputs provided to the procedure in which it is written.

```
        CREATE TRIGGER  '[trig'+@TableName + 'InsertLog]'  
        ON  'db.' + @TableName   
        AFTER INSERT
        AS
       [...]
```

But the above code throws an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER''.

Would appreciate any work around to the issue or insights on how to resolve it in this code.

Comment: No.  Trigger names are not generated dynamically.

Comment: Are you using Oracle? (Doesn't that code look more like SQL Server?)

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Is something wrong with code if it is SQL Server?

Comment: @NBaliga So why did you tag your question `plsql` if you're not using PLSQL? And why didn't you tag it with `sql-server`? You wouldn't get much success trying to Kia car parts to fix an Audi. ... Ask your question _correctly_ and you'll get better answers.

Comment: I've fixed the tags on your question; including removing the stored-procedures tag, because your question only mentions triggers and has nothing to do with stored procedures.

Comment: @CraigYoung thank you very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql. Consider the following:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'CREATE TRIGGER [trig' + @tableName + '_InsertLog]
ON dbo.' + @TableName + '
AFTER INSERT
AS ...'

execute @sql
```

Tweak as needed for your flavour of SQL.

---

## WARNING

That said, I'd like to caution you against this approach. You may think it's a convenient way to reuse code and/or ensure consistency. But the level of abstraction is not good, and you'll simply create more problems for yourself in the long run. E.g. This approach to logging is reactive. So when you actually try to use the logs you'll find:

- It's difficult to extract semantically useful information from the logs. (Ye it's there, but difficult to analyse.)
- Some logging will be missing because you cannot log things attempted but rolled back.

Comment: Thank you Craig. I did try the approach suggested by you before moving on to a stored procedure. However it did not work because of a mismatch between the data types of @sql and of multiple arguments of different data types in the body of the trigger.

Comment: @NBaliga That's a matter of casting what needs to be type-cast appropriately. I've answered the question presented. If you have a different question, you should create a **new** question and ensure you provide the correct details of what you're asking.